# Trying to delete records from a table that has 20 million records

Tags: sql, performance, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have this stored procedure that it is not finishing the execution at all. The table `TbARIAFLD3_ARIAFLD3Errors` has 20 million rows, could you please help me how to execute it faster? The `TbARIAFLD3Errors` table has 600000+ rows, and other tables aren't that bad but still have thousands of rows.

Could you please help me to execute it faster?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SspArchiveDeleteReportInstance]
AS
BEGIN

--------------------------------------------------
SET NOCOUNT ON
--------------------------------------------------

DECLARE @deleteTable TABLE([ReportInstanceId] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL)
Print 'Entered into the Store Procedure'
-- Do an inner join to pick up records that haven't been archived yet
INSERT @deleteTable 
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP 50 TbReportInstance.ReportInstanceId 
    FROM TbReportInstance
    INNER JOIN TbReportInstanceReportUnit ON TbReportInstanceReportUnit.ReportInstanceId = TbReportInstance.ReportInstanceId
    WHERE TbReportInstance.ArchiveFlag = 1
        
Print 'Before First Delete'
-- Delete everything that joins to the delete table
DELETE TbReportInstanceReportUnit 
FROM TbReportInstanceReportUnit
INNER JOIN @deleteTable DT ON TbReportInstanceReportUnit.ReportInstanceId = DT.ReportInstanceId

--Address Files
Print 'Before Large Statement'
DECLARE @deleteTbARIAFLD3Errors TABLE(Id int identity, ARIAFLD3ErrorId uniqueidentifier NOT NULL)
INSERT @deleteTbARIAFLD3Errors 
    select DISTINCT TbARIAFLD3Errors.ARIAFLD3ErrorId
    FROM TbARIAFLD3Errors with (nolock)
    INNER JOIN TbARIAFLD3_ARIAFLD3Errors with (nolock) ON TbARIAFLD3_ARIAFLD3Errors.ARIAFLD3ErrorId = TbARIAFLD3Errors.ARIAFLD3ErrorId
    INNER JOIN TbARIAFLD3 with (nolock) ON TbARIAFLD3.ARIAFLD3Id = TbARIAFLD3_ARIAFLD3Errors.ARIAFLD3Id
    INNER JOIN @deleteTable DT ON TbARIAFLD3.ReportInstanceId = DT.ReportInstanceId
Print '1st Large Statement Completed'

declare @count bigint, @loopCount bigint, @iterator int=1, @var uniqueidentifier
select @count=max(Id) from @deleteTbARIAFLD3Errors
select @count Counts
select @iterator = min(Id) from @deleteTbARIAFLD3Errors
--set @loopCount = @count/10000
select @iterator iterator

    WHILE (@iterator <= @count)
    BEGIN
        select top 1 @var =  ARIAFLD3ErrorId from @deleteTbARIAFLD3Errors DT where DT.Id=@iterator
        DELETE TbARIAFLD3_ARIAFLD3Errors
        FROM TbARIAFLD3_ARIAFLD3Errors where ARIAFLD3ErrorId = @var
        --INNER JOIn @deleteTbARIAFLD3Errors DT on TbARIAFLD3_ARIAFLD3Errors.ARIAFLD3ErrorId=DT.ARIAFLD3ErrorId
        --where DT.Id=@iterator
        
        set @iterator=@iterator+1       
    END
--------------------------------------------------
SET NOCOUNT OFF
--------------------------------------------------
END
```

Comment: Can you describe the logic in natural language? There is virtually no reason to ever loop through a table deleting records one by one.

Comment: Of course test this out thoroughly and take backups, etc... But as I'm reading this, it's not clear why something like this wouldn't work `DELETE TbARIAFLD3_ARIAFLD3Errors as tgt FROM TbARIAFLD3_ARIAFLD3Errors as del where tgt.ARIAFLD3ErrorId = del.uniqueIdentifier` .

Comment: It is not one by one its a foreign key I am checking to delete, can you please suggest me some alternate, because I tried by joining all the table with the Table Variable selected also. Still Stored Proc didn't execute. Thank you for you support.

Comment: It's one by one for every distinct value of id in deleteTbARIAFLD3Errors, no? Sample data and expected results really help in cases like this. It's not obvious why this loop is needed instead of the simple set operation.

Comment: I agree there seems no reason why you need a loop, but you also need to look at the execution plan. Maybe you have a lot of indexes on the table you are deleting from that would all need updating, maybe your server and/disks are slow. Have you checked for activity in activity monitor (in SSMS)? It's highly unlikely that a query will never finish unless the server runs out of resource/crashes etc.

Comment: Is there anyway I can add script in my Stored Procedure to clean up the Cache it already has? and do you want me to drop the indexes or PK on the Table before deleting the records?

Comment: Hi Alan, Error_2646, do you mean I need to drop the PK and non-clustered indexes my friend? It has only PK Index, is that fine or do you want me to drop that as well? It is jus the number of rows big and maybe Log file full or something inside, not the other reasons it seems. Even I changed to use Join to delete records, it is still the same, un-expected results, like just some records are deleted but not much or sometimes even no records deleted, each is giving different results.